# Instantiating collection objects

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

So let's say I have a generic object, Person. A person has a name and a gender - name must be a string, and gender must be `male` or `female`. I also have a collection object, PersonList, that has an array of Person objects and allows operations on the set (eg., return a list of people of a certain gender.)

On one hand, it'd be nice to create the PersonList with the data in the constructor...

```
list = new PersonList([new Person('Alice', 'Female'), ...]);
```

...but then we don't know if the data is valid. We can allow invalid Person objects in, and check their validity when we access them, or we can give Person a vaild() method and say...

```
list = new PersonList();
alice = new Person('Alice', 'Female');
if (alice->valid()) list->add(alice);
```

...or maybe we check valid() within add(). But it seems weird to me to have a valid() method at all.

Generally speaking, how would you instantiate these objects? Is this a subjective thing, or is there a universal "right way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust yourself never to create invalid objects, you don't really need a method to check validity. However, if you're going to be creating potentially invalid objects based on user data, then you should have a validity checking method, and calling that method should be the last thing the constructor does. If transformations to that object can occur that can render it invalid, said method should also be called immediately after said transformations occur. Invalid objects should be caught instantly, and the end user of the class should never have to worry about it, beyond being thrown the occasional exception.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So does it follow that we should never allow invalid objects into our list (rather than allowing them, but marking them as invalid and fixing them later)? And if our list constructor receives an invalid Person, how do we indicate that our list was not created as expected? That seems like an argument for not having a constructor, and instead making the user add() each Person individually.
...or is this all so specific that the answer is, "it depends"?

Comment: If you follow the guidelines I laid out above, there should never be any invalid Person objects, as any opportunity to create one is accompanied by a check to make sure that didn't happen. If there are no invalid Persons, your list never has to worry about the possibility. You can have a constructor for your PersonList if you like. Any invalid Person objects will be caught before PersonList's constructor ever sees them.

Comment: So you're saying to throw an exception as soon as Person is found to be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

1. A class like `PersonList` is not generic. It is coupled to `Person`.
2. It is unclear why you think your hard-coded data might not be valid.
3. If it is possible to construct an object that is in some sense invalid, then you should always have a method to test its validity in that sense.

Comment: 1. True, don't know why I said that.
2. It'd be user data.
3. Thanks!